# Building OpenSSH on OS X: configure: WARNING: sandbox.h: present but cannot be compiled

Tags: macos, openssh

I'm trying to build the latest openssh Portable on OS X. However, when I run ./confgure, this comes up:

```
configure: WARNING: sandbox.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: sandbox.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: sandbox.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: sandbox.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: sandbox.h: proceeding with the preprocessor's result
configure: WARNING: sandbox.h: in the future, the compiler will take precedence
configure: WARNING:     ## ------------------------------------------- ##
configure: WARNING:     ## Report this to openssh-unix-dev@mindrot.org ##
configure: WARNING:     ## ------------------------------------------- ##
checking for sandbox.h... yes
```

And when I try to build it:

```
In file included from sandbox-darwin.c:23:
/usr/include/sandbox.h:98:29: error: sandbox/private.h: No such file or directory
make: *** [sandbox-darwin.o] Error 1
```

Needless to say, this is a problem. I've searched Google and looked through the "Questions that may already have your answer", but nothing seems to be relevant. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to workaround this issue by adding a #define to the build command (as suggested [here](https://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2012-December/030895.html)):

```
gcc -D__APPLE_API_STRICT_CONFORMANCE -I . -c sandbox-darwin.c -o sandbox-darwin.o
```

Note: This is a minimal example of how to compile the sandbox-darwin.c you will probably need to add in appropriate other command line arguments depending your platform - just copy the build command and add in the -D__APPLE_API_STRICT_CONFORMANCE or add it the Makefile.

This something that I ran into recently (with openssh-6.8p1 and 6.9p1) and I'm not clear why this 'fix' wasn't included as part of openssh or Macports...? It may be due to the fact that it seems that this issue only affects OSX Lion 10.7, though I've not tested it on other versions...

Comment: I accepted your answer, but I can't test it myself as I no longer have access to an OS X machine--this question is, after all, three years old! It looks good though, and it should help other people if they run into the issue.